# ParaView programmable filter for contours

Tags: python, paraview

I'm trying to create a programmable filter to extract isosurfaces. I know that I can manually type in multiple Isosurfaces and get all of them extracted by a single filter. The problem with that is, that I have to manually type them in. In my use case, I have a bunch of isovalues that I want to use and thus it's kinda tedious to type them in manually.

I've tried using the programmable filter, but I'm kinda stuck on the data format I'm getting.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
pdi = self.GetPolyDataInput()
pdo =  self.GetPolyDataOutput() 
c = vtk.vtkContourFilter()
c.SetInputConnection(pdo)
c.SetValue(0, 0.01)
c.Update()
self.GetOutput().ShallowCopy(c.GetOutput())
```

The problem is, that pdo is "None", ie the I don't have PolyData. When I use *pdo =  self.GetOutput()* then I get a **vtkImageData** object. Which does not work as InputConnection for the ContourFilter.

My ideal solution would be a snipped of code where I just have to copy in a list of values with the rendered isosurfaces for these values, preferable as different objects, so I can color them and add/remove them from the current RenderView.

I'm using **raw data** as input

Comment: why do you want to use a programmable filter to do that ?

Comment: Honestly, I don't need a programmable filter, I just thought that's the way to go. I just want to paste in a list of isovalues instead of adding them one by one. If you have a different way to do that, let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Python shell to do just this. Click on the Contour object in the Pipeline Browser. Then, open the Python shell (Tools -> Python Shell). Execute the following lines of Python code in the shell:

```
contour = GetActiveSource()
contour.Isosurfaces = [100.0, 200.0, 300.0]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the following error:
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/paraview-5.4/site-packages/paraview/servermanager.py", line 453, in __setattr__
    "to add this attribute.")
AttributeError: Attribute Isosurfaces does not exist.  This class does not allow addition of new attributes to avoid mistakes due to typos. Use add_attribute() if you really want to add this attribute.

Comment: Hey, I've solved the problem. can you add to your answer that you have to have a Contour selected in the pipeline browser? Then it works fine.

Comment: I did say to click on the Contour object in the second sentence :-)